# How to take values from one column and move to another column while getting the absolute value of each record?

Tags: excel, vba

I have one column `H` for Awards. The value format is Number. 
I want to take all values in `H` (except for the header) and place them in another column `I`. However, I want the output to be the absolute value. 
If possible, I want to add onto my current code for concatenating two columns

```
Sub concatenate()

    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    'Uses Column A to set the 'lngLastRow' variable _
    (find the last row) - change if required.
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=A2:A" & lngLastRow & "&""_""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The `Row()` bit converts the result to an array which otherwise `Evaluate` won't do.

```
Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=if(row(2:" & lngLastRow & "),abs(A2:A" & lngLastRow & ")&""_""&" & "abs(B2:B" & lngLastRow & "))")
```

Or maybe just

```
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Range("I2:I" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=if(row(2:" & lngLastRow & "),abs(H2:H" & lngLastRow & "))")
```

Comment: HI SJR, it seems you had combined what I was looking for with what I already had haha. I have a column H with values that I want to pull and return the absolute value of in column I.

Comment: Have I misunderstood your question? From what you say why not just `=abs(h2)` etc?

Comment: Your edit worked perfectly! I'm new to VBA and used someone elses code as a reference, so I wasn't sure how to best manipulate like you did.